# How to sort ArrayList having custom objects in java having no pojo class?

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist, collections

I am trying to sort an `arraylist` that has custom objects. I want to sort my `arraylist` based on a property inside the object.

Below is my code:

```
List<Object[]> search = qry1.getResultList();
```

Below is my output:

```
"searchresults" = ArrayList<E> 
elementData=Object[33]
[0] = Object[10] 
    [0] = "Dog"
    [1] = "Animal"
    [2] = "Carnivorous"
[1] = Object[10]
    [0] = "Lion"
    [1] = "Animal"
    [2] = "Carnivorous"
[2] = Object[10]
    [0] = "Cow"
    [1] = "Animal"
    [2] = "Herbivorous"
[3] = Object[10]
    [0] = "Buffalo"
    [1] = "Animal"
    [2] = "Herbivorous"
```

Now i want to sort the result based on the animal name(**Buffalo, Dog, Lion**)

I tried using java 8 function but didnt work. Also tried using `comparator` but didnt work:

```
search.stream().sorted(comp1, comp2);
```

Please guide.

Comment: How is this duplicate.. Pls understand i dont have a pojo class here as in the question which has been marked for the reference.

Comment: @Schirish The solution is to use a custom comarator - just as it is answered in the other question. You don't have a POJO class, but this does not matter - you can implement a custom comparator for object arrays. So to speak `Object[]` is your POJO class.

Comment: as we can see people there have done object.getDate for eg what can i do in my case?

Comment: You want to sort a collection of `Object[]` over first entries, right. So write a `Comparator<Object[]>` and compare `value[0]`.

Comment: Thanks @lexicore :). It helped . Kayaman : The logic said by lexicore was nowhere present in the question marked for reference.

Comment: From my POV it is a duplicate. "Write a custom comparator" is the given answer. You could have adapted it to `Object[]`.